# Consistent placement for page number with changing margins

Tags: header-footer, margins, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I have a document (letter paper) with a cover letter, some single column pages and some two-column pages. For readability I would like to use 1.5" margins for the single column pages and 1" margins for the two-column pages. I've done this using the `geometry` package and `\newgeometry`. However, when I compile the document the pages numbers (centered) move up and down, higher with larger margins and lower with smaller margins.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{letterpaper, margin=1.5in, marginparsep=7pt, marginparwidth=.6in}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
hi

\newgeometry{margin=1in}  
\newpage
\begin{multicols}{2}
hello
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

I was wondering how I can keep the page number in a consistent position? **but**, I was also wondering what I **should** do, should I avoid these changing margins altogether? Should I leave it with the page numbers different on different pages?

I've tried:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

and calling `\fancyhfoffset[E,O]{0pt}` after each `\newgeometry` call but I figure something else must be needed to have the page number not move.

Comment: According to your MWE, using `\newgeometry{margin=1in,bottom=1.5in}` maintains a consistent page number height between the two formats. Is this what you're after? I would stick to a consistent stock dimension, but I'm not sure what the end result or usage of the document might be.

Comment: Have you tried setting the value of the `headsep` parameter of the `geometry` package? It controls the vertical separation between the header and the text block.

Comment: @Mico do you mean the `footskip`?

Comment: @DanielE.Shub: I somehow interpreted the question as implying that the page numbers are printed at the top rather than at the bottom of the page. If they're printed at the bottom, the relevant parameter would indeed be `footskip`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the footskip parameter

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{letterpaper, footskip=1in, margin=1.5in, marginparsep=7pt, marginparwidth=.6in}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
hi

\newgeometry{footskip=0.5in, margin=1in}
\newpage
\begin{multicols}{2}
hello
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```